# Cannot find $env package problem in sveltekit app

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to use environment variables in my svelte app following the sveltekit docs, but I keep getting the error message: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '$env' imported from...

I even tried creating a whole new app to test and the problem is still there.

[image: screenshot of project structure and files created]

Comment: Have you made sure the versions of dependencies between the SvelteKit Docs example and your local project are similar(or ideally the same) in the `package.json` file? Seems like a versioning issue...

Comment: Just checked the sveltekit tutorial example and the @sveltejs/kit version there is ^1.14.0 and in my project it is ^1.5.0 . Could this be the problem?

Comment: It might be. Try version 1.14.0 on your project and see.

Comment: Updated everything with npx npm-check-updates -u and then npm install and the problem continues

Comment: Just an update. I don't know what I did, but environment variables are now working

Comment: That's great. If you do find out how you got it to work post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Solved by creating .env file in project root. :-)